# How can I consolidate lines in a text file?

Tags: python-3.x, text

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
100 Spam
250 Spam
50  Spam
20  Eggs
70  Eggs
```

Now I want to consolidate the lines into a new file, such that it looks like this:

```
300 Spam
90  Eggs
```

I read the file line by line into a list. Now I am looping through each item in the list like this:

```
new_list = []
j = 1
for i in range(len(old_list)):
       new_list.append("")
       if old_list[i][4:] == old_list[i-j][4:]:
          new_list[i-j][:4] = str(int(old_list[i][:4].strip()) + int(old_list[i-j][:4].strip())).ljust(4)
          new_list[i-j][4:] = old_list[i-j][4:]
          j += 1
       else:
          new_list[i-j] = old_list[i-j]
```

I run into 2 problems with this:

1. I get a type error, saying that I cannot assign to string
2. Even without the error, I do not get the correct sum, when there are more than 2 lines to be added, because in the loop I overwrite the sum. I would need to somehow store this sum, but I cannot think of an elegant way to do this.

I am new to programming, so maybe there is a better way to approach the problem all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = {}

with open("your_file.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        amount, food_item = line.split()
        result[food_item] = result.get(food_item, 0) + int(amount)

print(result)  # {'Spam': 400, 'Eggs': 90}
```

Then you can write `result` out to a new file

```
with open("some_other_file.txt") as outfile:
    for food_item, amount in result.items():
        outfile.write(f"{amount} {food_item}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution is quite limited to the input you presented.
As a first, naive approach I'd divide the problem into 3 parts:

1. Parse input into a list of tuples.
   Read the input and create the `old_list`, where each element is a tuple (value, key)

```py
old_list = [(100, 'Spam'), (250, 'Spam'), (50, 'Spam'), (20, 'Eggs'), (70,'Eggs')]
```

2. Go through the old list and create a dict to accumulate the result

```py
result = {}
    for elem in old_list:
        if elem[1] in result:
            result[elem[1]] += elem[0]
        else:
            result[elem[1]] = elem[0]
```

For each element in `old_list` if you already saw an item with the same key, sum up its values and continue. Otherwise, add the key to the result dict with the present value.

3. Go through the result dict and write the file down.

```
result = {'Spam': 400, 'Eggs': 90}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file = open("file.txt", "w+")
input = file.read().split("\n")

output = {}
for line in input:
    line = line.split(" ")
    if line[1] in output:
        output[line[1]] += int(line[0])
    else:
        output[line[1]] = int(line[0])

for line in output:
    file.write(line + " " + str(output[line]) + "\n")
```